# No carga la función al primer click

Tags: javascript, función-personalizada

Tengo un botón de un sol y una luna en el código HTML.

El botón del sol activa el modo claro de la página y el botón de la luna activa el modo oscuro.

Si en tu ordenador tienes activado los ajustes de visión de pantalla en modo claro la página se te cargará en modo claro automáticamente. Si quieres cambiar el aspecto de la página a oscuro, deberás hacer click en la luna, y cargará la función darkmode() que entre otras cosas hace visible el botón del sol, oculta el botón de luna, y pone el fondo en negro y las letras en blanco.

En cambio, si en tu ordenador tienes activado los ajustes de visión de la pantalla en modo oscuro la página se cargará en modo oscuro automáticamente. Si quieres cambiar el aspecto de la página a claro, deberás hacer click al sol, pero esta vez, y no encuentro el por qué, tendrás que darle dos veces. Y ese es el problema que tengo.

Dejo por aquí el código necesario:

```
<!--HTML-->

<img id="sol" class="sol" src="images/sol.png" alt="Modo día" onclick="darkMode()"</img>

<img id="luna" class="luna" src="images/luna.png" alt="Modo noche" onclick="darkMode()"></img>


/*JS*/


let dark;

//DETECTA SI EL DISPOSITIVO TIENE ACTIVADO EL MODO OSCURO O CLARO
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.matches) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
      dark = true;
    } else {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
      dark=false;
    }
  });


function darkMode() {


    if(dark == false){

        dark = true;

        document.getElementById("luna").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("sol").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("header").style.setProperty("background-color","black","important");
        document.querySelector("header").style.setProperty("background-color","black");

        //Cambia el cuerpo a oscuro
        document.getElementsByClassName("div-form")[0].style.setProperty("background-color", "black", "important");

        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[0].style.color = "white";
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[1].style.color = "white";
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[2].style.color = "white";

        document.getElementById("footer").style.setProperty("background-color","black","important");
        document.querySelector("footer").style.setProperty("background-color","black","important");

        document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.border = "solid white";


        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[0].style.setProperty("color", "white" , "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[1].style.setProperty("color", "white", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[2].style.setProperty("color", "white", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[3].style.setProperty("color", "white", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[4].style.setProperty("color", "white", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[5].style.setProperty("color", "white", "important");
    }
    
    else{

        dark = false;

        document.getElementById("sol").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("luna").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("header").style.setProperty("background-color","white","important");
        document.querySelector("header").style.setProperty("background-color","white","important");

        document.getElementsByClassName("div-form")[0].style.setProperty("background-color", "white", "important");

        document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.border = "solid black";


        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[0].style.setProperty("color", "inherit", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[1].style.setProperty("color", "inherit", "important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[2].style.setProperty("color", "inherit", "important");

        document.querySelector("footer").style.setProperty("background-color","white","important");

        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[0].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[1].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[2].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[3].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[4].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
        document.getElementsByClassName("text-muted")[5].style.setProperty("color", "inherit","important");
    } 
  }
```

Imagino que será un fallo debido a que la variable dark no esté definida desde el principio, pero he probado a asignarle false, y tampoco funciona el botón a la primera.